# Kaspersky block SignalR messages with error 404

Tags: .net, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, kaspersky

I use `.net core 5` and `SignalR` to send some data to UI (`angular 10`).
In any client that has Kaspersky installed, I get an error message:

[image]

[image]

This is `negotiate` message:

[image]

and this is response:

[image]

I searched in Kaspersky blogs and found that this error shows that Antivirus blocked the handshake process.
If I uninstall Kaspersky, everything will be fine but I have to keep Antivirus.

Comment: Did you try open link in browser? What message you have in the browser? Do you use https connection? Maybe communication is blocked because is unencrypted? I'm only guessing.

Comment: I have no message in browser. I use https. I will check encryption. What if all of these conditions are met ans still have error? I am thinking of removing signalR and managing all cyclic events on UI side.